# Getting the ipv6 address in python doesnt work

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6

So I have been using the following method lately proposed here: [Return IPv6 address Python from domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775365/return-ipv6-address-python-from-domain-naim) in order to get IPv6 addresses of some sites:

```
def getIPv6Addr(input):
    socket.getaddrinfo(input, None, socket.AF_INET6)
```

The method was working a couple of days ago nevertheless, when I use it now it gives me None as a response. For example `print getIPv6Addr("www.google.com")` returns `None` whereas it should return `2a00:1450:400c:c01::69`.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: `socket.getaddrinfo("google.com", None, socket.AF_INET6)` returns `[(10, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:4004:801::1001', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('2607:f8b0:4004:801::1001', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('2607:f8b0:4004:801::1001', 0, 0, 0))]` for me.  Perhaps your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: but where else could the problem be?

Comment: The problem might be in your DNS resolution infrastructure. On Linux, try "host www.google.com" and look for a line like "www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400f:800::1010".

Comment: thing is the method was working yesturday! i dont know what went wrong. im not THAT worried about what comes back but something has to come back from the query because yday i made a list using that method of ipv6 enabled servers.

Comment: I think this is more a misconfiguration in your operating system or DNS resolvers than a programming error.

Comment: hmmm what sort of misconfiguration tho? i have no idea..

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you constructed the call to `getaddrinfo` correctly, but you didn't `return` the value.

Try this:

```
def getIPv6Addr(input):
    return socket.getaddrinfo(input, None, socket.AF_INET6)
```